# error document not geting redirect in wamp server

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I'm using wamp server 3.0.4 and apache version 2.4.18.I want to redirect 404 pages to custom pages. I have enabled `LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so` in `apache/conf/httpd.conf` and changed in `apache/conf/httpd.conf`:

```
<Directory "c:/wamp64/www/">
Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride all  #none to all
Require local
</Directory>
```

In httpd.vhost

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName testblog
    DocumentRoot c:/wamp64/www/testblog
    <Directory  "c:/wamp64/www/testblog/">
        Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require local
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

and restart the server.

In my htaccess file I have the following code

```
ErrorDocument 404 https://www.test.com/not-found.html

RedirectMatch 301 /learn   https://www.test.com/not-found.html
```

But not able to redirect .What I missed here

Comment: _Redirecting_ externally to a 404 document is completely the wrong thing to do to begin with. Search engines and other automated tools will _not_ get the 404 status code for the originally requested URL any more. Instead, they will consider the URL of the 404 you just redirected to, as the one that does “not exist.”

Comment: What happens exactly? An error? Nothing? Are you accessing the site from the same machine that is hosting the webserver?  An inconsistency with the code above is that you are using `www.test.com` in your "redirect", but your vHost states `ServerName testblog`?

Comment: Keep mod_rewrite enabled and then trying this in your .htaccess file: Add ```RewriteEngine On```, then after that add this line, ```RewriteRule ^learn https://www.test.com/not-found.html [R=302,L]```

Comment: @MrWhite I think that it is not giving a 301 response. Or maybe weirdly it is not sending the Location header, but that is rarely the case. Also, clearing the cache is a good thing here in this case. Also the inconsistency is mostly because of stackoverflow, which might be forcing the OP not to use their own domain, so therefore might be a typo. But you are right in a way in that. Because I don't know if they are trying to redirect c:/wamp64/www or c:/wamp64/www/testblog. And also the forward slash after the directory is weird. I have never seen trailing slash after directory in apache conf.

Comment: @Chi.C.J.RajeevaLochana From the limited information given it would seem the directives in `.htaccess` aren't doing "anything" at all. (?) They should be doing "something", even if that _something_ is incorrect. This would seem to suggest that `AllowOverride All` is not being set correctly - in the wrong config, not included or overridden perhaps? There's also other inconsistencies here... MultiViews is explicitly enabled in the vHost:80 - why? This could conflict with the `RedirectMatch` directive, depending on the filesystem. (The trailing slash on the _directory_ argument is optional.)

Comment: @MrWhite, Yeah, `AllowOverride All` might be the real culprit. And also `MultiVeiws`. Anyways, should I keep my answer or delete it? The OP is anyways not respinding

Comment: @Chi.C.J.RajeevaLochana Keep your answer; you never know. :)

Comment: @MrWhite, I am not sure that the comment reaches the OP, when you target a persion with @ in stackoverflow. I am not sure.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208433/discussion-between-chi-c-j-rajeeva-lochana-and-mrwhite).

Comment: I have moved this to chat. lol, the comments are too long

Answer (score 0):

Keep mod_rewrite enabled and then trying this in your .htaccess file:

Add the following to it at the top:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^learn https://www.test.com/not-found.html [R=302,L]
```

`RedirectMatch` uses mod_alias, so make sure you have enabled that, it should be enabled automatically, but rarely it might not be, so enable it and try your redirect. Even after that, if it does not work, stick with the above. Let me know if you have any questions.